# Creating an array of Objects from reading a .txt file and saving line by line into object array

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

The project prompt looks like this: In Netbeans create a project named Project1, be sure to create a package, DO NOT use the default package. There will be two java files, the first most likely named Project1.java (which contains main) and the second named Record.java which contains a variable containing ONE LINE OF DATA (or record) read from the file. 
In your main class (not in Record.java) create an array of Record objects. When the program starts have main() call a method that reads each line of text from the file, creates a Record object containing that line and places the object in the next available slot of the array.

The text file I have saved is this:

```
John, Doe, jd@yahoo.com, 123456, green, 19.24
Mary, Jane, maryj@gmail.com, 7654321, blue, 27.54
Curly, Howard, nyuknyuk@msn.com, 888765, purple, 0.0
Bart, Simpson, donthaveacow@hotmail.com, 457673, magenta, 432.23
Clark, Kent, superdude@dailyplanet.com, 976834, red, 11.10
```

My Issue is not understanding how to read from the text file line by line and storing it in an array of Objects Record. I can create an array of Strings easily but it does not really help the situation. I am not sure if I am making it more complicated then it has to be or if I am completely wrong.
 SO far this is my code

```
project1:
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project1 {
protected static int arrayLength=5 ;
protected static String filename ="data.txt";

   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
     Record [] objects = new Record[arrayLength];
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
     Record obj = (Record) in.readObject();
     System.out.print(obj.getRecord());
   }

   public static void arrayObjects()throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
     Record [] objects = new Record[arrayLength];
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
     Record obj = (Record) in.readObject();



      }
       }
package Project1;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.*;; 



    /**
     *
     * @author lexif
     */
    public class Record{
     private String path;
     private String data;
     private int number =1;
    public Record(String file_path) throws IOException{
        path = file_path;

      }
    public String getRecord() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileReader open = new FileReader(path); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(open);
        String data1 = reader.readLine();
        return data1;
    }

    public String OpenFile(String filename,int num) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader (filename);
        BufferedReader textreader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
        data = textreader.readLine();
        }
        textreader.close();
        return data;
        }

     public int readLines () throws IOException{
           FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

           String aline;
           int numLines=0;

           while((aline = br.readLine()) != null){
               numLines++;
           }
           br.close();
           return numLines;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code

```
   public Record[] readRecord(String pathFile) throws IOException {
        List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(pathFile));
        Record[] records = new Record[list.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++) {
            records[i] = new Record(list.get(i));
        }
        return records;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you but I believe yours does not save one line into the array of objects

Comment: When you read text from file. Each line is one item of list. Then you create records from each item.

Comment: Oh I see so i would pass **readRecord** the data string I have already read from **openfile** ?

Comment: You don't need to use openfile function. Because my function includes open file, read file and save into the Record[] records

Comment: I see that now Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nguyen Hung Hau it actually doesn't work or I am making a mistake. as i write this code it does not give me the answer. **case 1: 
        int num; 
        arrayLength = count(filename);
        System.out.println("Enter Record Number 0-" + (arrayLength-1));
         num= Record.getInt(0,arrayLength-1);
         Record [] obj =readRecord (filename);
         System.out.println(obj[num]);** the system prints out **Enter Record Number 0-4
2
Project1.Record@1b84c92**

Comment: @AlexisFlanigan 
obj[num] is an object, so you can't print it. If you want to print a line in file, please use System.out.println(obj[num].getData())

Comment: what would **.getData()** look like as one of the instructions for my project is to call an object record method with prints the one line of code from a created record array object **arrayLength = count(filename);
        System.out.println("Enter Record Number 0-" + (arrayLength-1));
         int num= Record.getInt(0,arrayLength-1);
         Record [] obj =readRecord (filename);** 
          This line does what i want by getting the file name and printing the number of the file received from the user. **String b = Record.OpenFile(filename, num);
         System.out.println(b);**

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have the readLines() function in the Project class. Then
What all you have to do is you need to modify your readLines() function to create the RecordObject and return the List of RecordObjects. Something like this

```
public List<Record> readLines () throws IOException{
    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

    String aline;
    int numLines=0;
    List<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<Record>();
    while((aline = br.readLine()) != null){

        Record rec = new Record(); // You can have a constructor which takes string as parameter also
        rec.setData(aline);
        recordList.add(rec);
        numLines++;
    }
    br.close();
    return recordList;
}
```

You don't need the OpenFile function in your record class and the getRecord should return only the 'data' member

Comment: I am not allowed to use a list, only an array of objects.

Comment: I did just change one method in projects to assign the Record line into the array of objects I created.                                                                                                                    **public static void arrayObjects()throws IOException{
     Record [] objects = new Record[arrayLength];
     for (int i =0;i < arrayLength;i++){
         objects[i]= new Record(filename);**

Comment: Sure, instead of List you can populate an array and return from the readLines()method. It is a simple change