# How do I automatically open and use a local file content as variable data?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Hello I would like to my html open automatically a local file like "records.txt" (without manually input a file with `<input type="file">`) and make all data as variable so I can manipulate later. As far as I know `<object data="records.txt">` can open automatically a file and read it but I don't know how to make it variable for use.

Comment: Have you hought about utilizing cache or cookies instead of a local file? Because of security reasons you will not be able to write to it. Another option is to use `window.localStorage` or `window.sessionStorage`

Comment: Browsers are not designed to access files without user. If so, it would be insecure and noone would use that browser. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779172/creating-an-array-of-objects-from-reading-a-txt-file-and-saving-line-by-line-in)?

Comment: @zergski how do I use cache or cookies ? I'm a new at programing (noob) if you can make a little piece of example code I would really appreciate.

(at)wazz sorta, I found "d3.v3.min.js" but I don't need a table I just want to use to search, input data and receive another, etc from a file.
Thanks.

Comment: well.. for starters.. what kind of data are you looking to handle?

Comment: @zergski names, times, date, etc...  is it possible to use console to send and receive my file data ? I can put all my texts and numbers data from my .txt in console but I don't know if I can use things like `document.getElementById('').value` on it.

Comment: That is possible! What you're looking for is Node and its filesystem. Though you will be able to write only to accessible devices and/or servers. So maybe use a database?

Comment: An offline database ? I'm trying to do something for an offline non server connected pc without using php or mysql (because I'm noob and I'm trying to start with javascritp and html)

Comment: easier with php though.. the script syntax is literally: `writef( jsonObj )`

Comment: Though you will only be able to do so on permitted devices, i.e server or local. If you're looking to store data on a user client look up `window. ocalStorage` alt. `window. sessionStorage` but that data isn't permanent